# linux shell execute an SQL query

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, psql

I am trying to perform an sql query after being logged to the database. Although the Postgres official documentation mentions option c, I just keep getting error saying that command , -c, --c are not valid options.

Below is the line in my shell script file.

```
psql "host='localhost' port=xxxx dbname='xxxxx' user='xxxx' password='xxxxx' -c='sql string'"
```

Comment: What's with the double quotes? (btw, _in general_, putting a password on a command line is a Very Bad Idea; it's somewhat safer to put it on the left-hand side of the command where it goes into the environment; putting it on the right-hand side means everyone/everything on the system can see it with `ps`).

Comment: I just keep getting an error message saying that the  c option in invalid.

Comment: (that doesn't mean we need your password etc, but we _do_ need something that fails the same way as your real command when run without changes, and the _exact_ error message, not an English paraphrase of it)

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. The psql is called from a *.sh file. I basically run the file in a terminal.

Comment: If I remove the c option everything just work. I will have to type my select statement by hand in the terminal

Comment: Regarding your first comment,  a connection string followed with an sql query are between the double quotes.

Comment: But `-c` is not legitimately part of a connection string. It needs to be its own argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238522/discussion-between-nesan-mano-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: See the [psql man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/psql): `-c` and the sql string must be separate arguments. You are lumping everything together into a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing long and short option syntax ...

This:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Connect to DB"
psql "host='localhost' port=xxxx dbname='xxxxx' user='xxxx' password='xxxxx'" -c='select * from pg_stat_archive'
```

needs to be:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Connect to DB"
psql "host='localhost' port=xxxx dbname='xxxxx' user='xxxx' password='xxxxx'" -c 'select * from pg_stat_archive'
```

The equal-sign is only used for the long-form: `--command=command`

Comment: It does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use a here doc in your shell script to avoid the termination and behavior of the -c

psql <<EOF
\x
SELECT * FROM foo;
EOF

See this for the specific behavior and examples
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html

Answer (score 0):

-c option has to to put in the front based on the comment by @Charles Duffy

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Connect to DB"
psql -c 'select * from any_table' "host='localhost' port=xxxx dbname='xxxxx' user='xxxx' password='xxxxx'"
```

Comment: Please format your posting, so that the code lines are displayed in separate lines.